# Inverse Z-transform $\frac{1+2\cdot z^{-1}}{1-0,5\cdot z^{-1}}$

Tags: z-transform

I'm trying to do the inverse Z-transform of:
$$H(Z)=\frac{1+(2\cdot z^{-1})}{1-(0,5z{^-1})}$$

My first thought was to divide the expression into two additions:

$H1(Z) = \frac{1}{1-(0,5z^{-1})}$

$H2(Z) = \frac{2\cdot z^{-1}}{1-(0,5\cdot z^{-1})}$

$h1(n)$ would then be $(0,5)^{n}\cdot u(n)$

I cannot find $h2(n)$

Is this even the right way to go when I want to find $h(n)$? Or should I maybe use the fact that $H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(Z)}$ and work from there? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the basic $\mathcal{Z}-$transform pair

$$\frac{1}{1-az^{-1}}=\frac{z}{z-a}\Longleftrightarrow a^nu(n)$$

(where $u(n)$ is the step function.)

Write $H(z)$ as you did:

$$H(z)=\frac{1}{1-0.5z^{-1}}+2\frac{z^{-1}}{1-0.5z^{-1}}$$

Multiplication by $z^{-1}$ is just a shift by one sample. So the inverse transform of $H(z)$ is given by

$$H(z)\Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu(n)+2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}u(n-1)$$

Comment: Just wonder about the last line. Isn’t 2 * (½)^(n-1) = 2 * (½)^(n) * (½)^(-1) = 2 * (½)^(n) * 2 = 4 * (½)^(n)?
In that case I don’t see how you got the last part of the line. Thanks for helping me out:)

Comment: @user264230 Yes, I made a mistake, thanks! Just corrected it.